# Prevent browser from downloading linked file

Tags: html, text, hyperlink, href

`<a href="/scripts/script.pde" target="_blank"></a>`

I want the browser to display this file as text in a new window. When clicked, it downloads onto the user's computer.

Comment: When a file downloads rather than being displayed in a browser, it's because the server serving up the file has told the browser that either 1) it's file type that the browser isn't suited to display or 2) the browser is meant to download the file. There isn't typically a way using HTML to control what a server sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your server how to hand out those files. In Apache, [you would do this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) in your config:

```
AddType text/plain .pde
```